# Ansys Maxwell reluctance motor design

Tags: current, current-measurement

I am working on a simulation of a reluctance motor in Ansys Maxwell. I used the field calculator and also the transient report to measure current in each winding.  It gives 0 in the field calculator, although it is like 59 A as shown in the plot. How I can fix it?

Comment: FYI, this probably isn't the best place to ask because there are only a few people that use ANSYS here.